# Unity URP 2D light

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've recently discovered the URP and am developing a 2D game for fun. I added a global 2d light and set up some code to grab the light component, but unity keeps saying that light 2D does not exist. The error in unity is "error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Light2D' could not be found". This is the code I have so far. I also followed a tutorial by Jimmy Vegas to grab the system time.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class DayNight : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject theDisplay;
    public GameObject GL;
    public int hour;
    public int minutes;
    public int totaltime;
    private bool AM;

    void Start()
    {
        totaltime = System.DateTime.Now.Hour;
        hour = System.DateTime.Now.Hour;
        minutes = System.DateTime.Now.Minute;
    }

        
    public void Night()
    {
        //change light settings
        GL.GetComponent<Light2D>().Intensity = 0.4;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To reference the `Light2D` Component you need to add the `UnityEngine.Experimental.Rendering.Universal` namespace to your code.

**Namespace Example:**

```cs
...
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Experimental.Rendering.Universal;

public class DayNight : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...
}
```

If you get an Error you need to just continue and try to compile it, to see if it actually works.

---

After that is done you should be able to access the `Light2D` Component of your `GameObject` without any further troubles.

**Calling Light2D Example:**

```cs
public float nightvalue = 0.4f;

public void Night()
{
    // Change light intensity to nightvalue.
    GL.GetComponent<Light2D>().intensity = nightvalue;
}
```